# Using curl with graphql issue

Tags: magento2, graphql, curl

I made the schema.grapqhs with this content:

```
type Query {
    quoteData (
        id: Int @doc(description: "Id of the Quote Data")
    ): QuoteData @resolver(class: "Vendor\\Module\\Model\\Resolver\\QuoteData") @doc(description: "The Quote Data Query Returns Data about a Quote Object")
}
type QuoteData @doc(description: "Quote information by quote id") {
    base_currency_code: String @doc(description: "Base Currency Code from Quote Object")
    grand_total: String @doc(description: "Grand Total of Specific Quote Object items")
    customer_name: String @doc(description: "Customer Name from Quote Object")
}
```

In my code, I am using curl to get the result of my query. This is the script:

```
        $endpoint = "http://magento.local/graphql";
        $query = '{
    quoteData(id: 1) {
        base_currency_code
        customer_name
        grand_total
    }
}';

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->getBearerToken();

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        if ((int) $info['http_code'] !== 200) {
            var_dump($info['http_code']); exit();
        }
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $body = substr($response, $header_size);
        var_dump($body); exit();
```

The result of my var_dump is:

```
{"errors":[{"debugMessage":"Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error","message":"Internal server error","extensions":{"category":"internal"},"trace":[{"file":"\/vendor\/magento\/module-graph-ql\/Controller\/GraphQl.php","line":184,"call":"Magento\\Framework\\Serialize\\Serializer\\Json::unserialize('{\n    quoteData(id: 1) {\n        base_currency_code\n        customer_name\n        grand_total\n    }\n}')"},  ......
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I missed the: `\n` from my `$query` variable, so i changed into this:

```
$query = '{"query":"query {\n quoteData(id: 1) {\n base_currency_code\n customer_name\n grand_total\n }\n}"}';
```

and it works!